# Add new column with the colname of the hisgest value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I have a dataframe such as

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 
1    2    3
3    2    1
2    4    8 
3    4    1
```

and I would like to create a new column where I put for each row the `COL name` with the `highest value`.
Then I should get:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 Newcol
1    2    3    COL3
3    2    1    COL1 
2    4    8    COL3
3    4    1    COL2
```

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: `df$NewCol <- names(df)[max.col(df)]`

Comment: what if there are also other columns ?

Comment: You can subset only interested columns. `df$NewCol <- names(df)[1:3][max.col(df[1:3])]`

Comment: thank you very much